# Prove or disprove $P(AB)≤P(A)P(B)$

Tags: probability, self-study

Prove That $P(AB)≤P(A)P(B)$

I have tried in this way,

$P(A)≥P(AB)$

$P(B)≥P(AB)$

Now, $P(A)P(B)≥P(AB)²$

But I am unable to prove or disprove the required result.

Comment: When $B$ is a subset of $A$, $P(A,B)=P(B) > P(A)P(B)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=B$, then we have

$$P(A ) \le P(A)^2$$

which is clearly not true if $0<P(A) < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume $P(AB)=P(A\cap B)$. The expression is incorrect. Take $A=B$, then we’ll have $P(A)\geq P(A)^2$, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The correlation between events $A$ and $B$ is given by:

$$\mathbb{Corr}(A,B) = \mathbb{P}(AB) - \mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B).$$

Thus, we have the inequality $\mathbb{P}(AB) \leqslant \mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B)$ if and only if these events are *not positively correlated*.  This is not true in general, and hence cannot be proved without some further assumptions on the events.